# Interakt replacement module for Dreamweaver OR PHP editor

Tags: php, dreamweaver, replace

I have worked for years with Dreamweaver and Interakt extensions to build hundreds of PHP websites. Interakt was great for me because I could develop PHP websites and small back offices in a couple of hours. Integrated modules like 'file upload', image resizing, automatic table creation,... were tools I used and that I still need today...

But Interakt has been bought by Adobe, and Interakt extensions are not more compatible with Dreamweaver CS3/CS4.

Does anybody knows any standalone software of module that could replace that?

Thank's to all.
Rohan

Answer (score 0):

Check out zend, cakephp, or any other updated php framwork and it will accomplish a lot of the overhead for you.